# Ubuntu 12.10 Bose Companion 5 not working

Tags: 12.10, sound, pulseaudio

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10,and I can see it in the list of inputs. But when I select  it then no sound I have tried restarting pulse audio demon and I have tried purging .pulse and .pulse-cookie directory as well. As I said it is visible in list but after selection no sound I have tried changing the 5.1 and 4.1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to unmute a volume control in `alsamixer`. In simple steps:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `alsamixer`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   A sort of GUI will be presented.
3. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select 'Bose'.
4. Increase the volume on the PCM channel using the arrow keys.

   *I am not sure it is the right volume control, since there was no master and all.*

More details are here: [Howto- Resolve Nosound Problem On Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04 And Older](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: This is not specific for any Bose product - any sound card can have this error, so your solution is universal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with Ubuntu/PulseAudio. Instead the problem was with the Bose Companion 5 System.

I turned off the Companion 5 system for 20 seconds, using the switch at the back of the subwoofer, then I switched it back on, and voilá! No need to reboot Ubuntu, the 'Bose' output device disappeared and re-appeared during the process, and now the sound is going out fine.

I usually leave the Bose system on 24x7, plugged into a power surge protected line, but for some reason, it seems like it crashed. A reboot of the Companion 5 was the solution.